# OpenCV Count Vehicles

Tags: opencv, count

I am bit new with Opencv / C++. I have been learning Opencv for last few months and trying to do work on a project to count persons in a video.

would you please tell me how to count only one time. I draw a virtual line on the image and when the centroid of bounding box crosses then increase by 1. But it counts multiple time of a single person . would you please suggest me how to do it.

1. Background subtraction MOG
2. Filters
3. Find Contours
4. Drawcontours
5. Draw Rectangles
6. Centroid Rectangles

Br.y is Bounding Box Bottom

if (center.y < 270 && Br.y > 272) { incr++;}

Regards Shan

Comment: Why not simply count the number of rectangles you drew?

Comment: Track the detected person/vehicle and dont count if already tracked

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  @a-Jays Yes i can count the rectangles i drew but sometime it drew false rectangles. @ Micka .... Would you please give me idea with code. if i track and not count again... Regards

Comment: If it draws false rectangles, then you need to work on your detection algorithm. Nothing else can counter that.

Comment: Check the example in samples\c\motempl.c